# Turning off hostnamelookup in a shared hosting

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel, shared-hosting

I have a linux shared hosting account with cpanel for a drupal website. While optimizing the site (with the help of information from tools.pingdom.com), I found considerable waiting time of about 400-500 ms. Somehow, I found out about 'hostnamelookup'. But I am not able to figure out how to turn it off in a shared hosting account (as we cannot change the .conf file of server). Can this be done in .htaccess ?. Thank you.

Comment: No, it can't be set in htaccess context.

Comment: So is there any other way of doing it in a shared hosting ?

Comment: You should ask your hosting provider. Shared hosting usually means that global settings cannot be changed.

Comment: 400-500 ms lost in that? to resolve your domain name?